# Javascript: Equalled elements does not inherit the functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have a div in HTML that contains a Select with working options that triggers an event  when changed. When I equal the innerHTML of a temporary row to the div that has the Select, it shows the select with the options, but when you click it, nothing happens. When I inspect element it, it shows it has the same values and IDs, but it doesn't seem to work. Weird question, I know. Thanks for the help.

```
document.getElementById(updatedStatus + '-noterow-temp').innerHTML = document.getElementById(channelToBeUpdated + '-noterow').innerHTML;
```

`updatedStatus+'-noterow-temp'` is the duplicate of the div and `channelToBeUpdated+'-noterow'` is the original div with the Select. In the view, it works and displays the Select tag, but the duplicate doesn't trigger the events when the options in the select are changed. Here's my question; How will I equal these two divs, display the Select, and get it working? Thanks!

Comment: Event handlers usually aren't stored in the HTML.

Comment: How are you duplicating the element? I assume you're copying the HTML - you need to also copy the events assigned to those elements. Have a look at `clone()` in the jQuery API.

Comment: Ok ill try the clone() @rory.

Comment: great it works! now how to do it if it is on tr inside a table `$( "#"+channelToBeUpdated+"-geninforow" ).clone().appendTo( "#"+updatedStatus+"-geninfo-temp" );` works but if use the ID of a tr, it messes up the HTML.